# Why can't I hide/show a label in didSelectRowAtIndexPath in tableview, iOS, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, hidden, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a table view and and I use two custom cells. in custom cell I have set a uilabel and hidden. Now when user select a cell from the table view, in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, I want to show that label.I tried it with follow,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HoteldetalcelloneTableViewCell *cellone = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellone"];
    HoteldetailcelltwoTableViewCell *celltwo = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"celltwo"];


    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        HotelDetailsone *secone = [roomonearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if([secone.offerallow isEqualToString:@"True"])
        {
            celltwo.selectedsignLabel.hidden = NO;


        }
        else
        {
            cellone.selectedsignLabelone.hidden = NO;



        }
        NSLog(@"price for room 1 : %@", secone.itempriceText);

    }
    else
    {
        HotelDetailsone *sectwo = [roomtwoarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"price for room 2 : %@", sectwo.itempriceText);
    }

}
```

**NOTE : I used a break point and checked, it navigate through correct statement.but nothing happen**

I tried with following also,

```
[cellone.selectedsignLabelone setHidden:NO];
```

but nothing happen.hope your help with this.thanx.

Comment: Have you verified that the labels exist?  That they have a non-zero size?  That they have any text?

Comment: yes,only "✓" sign available.

Comment: **Do not manipulate the view (the table view cell) outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`**. Add a property `selected` to the model (the type of the items in the data source array), handle it in `cellForRow...` and reload the table view.

Comment: How many sections do you have here?

Comment: multiple selections

Comment: Anuradh I tried sample for your question.I got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `UITableView` re-uses cells to save memory: When you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` you get a cell object that is going to be changed the next time the table view will need to draw a cell, so when you change it, it will be thrown away afterwards.

The cell object that's actually loaded and shown is returned in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Try to modify the cell inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellone"];
   if (indexPath == selectedIndexPath ) // this is the selected cell
   { 
      cell.selectedsignLabelone.hidden = NO;
   }
   return cell;
}
```

If you want to update your cells inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, try to `[tableView reloadData]` in the end and replace `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

As you used custom cell, I think it might be an autolayout issue.
It's working but the label goes out of bound . Can you please check that?

Comment: no, I have tried `show` and `hide` at that time it shows correctly and cannot hide.

Answer (score 0):

If you select or click the table view row only,it shows the label from hidden state to visible and also shows the data in label.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"


@interface ViewController ()
{
   NSMutableArray *arrCustomCellOne,*arrCustomCellTwo,*arraySection;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tblviewTwoCustomCell;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  arrCustomCellOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Tim Cook",@"Sathya Nadella",@"Mark",@"Sundaram Pichai",nil];
  arrCustomCellTwo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Microsoft",@"Facebook",@"Google",nil];
  arraySection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Name",@"Company",nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return arraySection.count;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if(section == 0)
   {
     return @"Name";
   }
   else
   {
     return @"Company";
   }
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if(section==0)
     return arrCustomCellOne.count;
  else
     return arrCustomCellTwo.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
   NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
   if([[arraySection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]isEqualToString:@"Name"])
   {
      if(cell == nil)
        cell = nibs[0];

      cell.lblName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrCustomCellOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   }
   if([[arraySection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]isEqualToString:@"Company"])
   {
       if(cell == nil)
          cell = nibs[1];

       cell.lblCompany.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrCustomCellTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   }  
   return cell;
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDlegate Methods

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   if([[arraySection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]isEqualToString:@"Name"])
   {
      cell.lblName.hidden = NO;
      cell.lblName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrCustomCellOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   }
   else
   {
      cell.lblCompany.hidden = NO;
      cell.lblCompany.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrCustomCellTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 35;
}

@end
```